# Horror comic about a vampire in space on a (possible) generation ship

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror

In the 1970s or early 1980s, I remember reading a horror comic from a rack in a grocery store. I don't even remember the publishing company's name, unfortunately.

It may have been one of several stories in the comic book, but I can't remember.

In the particular story I recall, a man awakens from cryogenic sleep or suspended animation of some sort, to find many other pods of the same type have been opened. The desiccated bodies of the other passengers/crew (I don't know which they were) are crumpled in front of them (the pods are vertical).

It turns out one of the passengers/crew was a vampire and he's been drinking the blood of the people in the other pods until only the central/protagonist character is left.

The vampire and the human have a chase around the ship and there's a self-destruct sequence set off either in the main ship or in the escape pod (but I think the human detonated the main ship and escaped in a shuttle or escape pod). But the vampire is on the same vehicle, and as he's closing in on the surviving human...

> ...the other vehicle explodes; the light from the explosion casts a sharp-contrast shadow through the view port in the shape of a cross that burns the vampire to ash.

Can anyone help identify the comic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be ["The Stars, Like Pallbearers"](http://creatfeatforever.blogspot.com/2015/12/the-stars-like-pallbearers.html) from [*Secrets of the Haunted House* #5.](https://www.comics.org/issue/29292/) The opening page contains the image you recall of desiccated bodies fallen out of vertical suspension tubes:

[image: On the first page of The Stars, like Pallbearers, space traveler Frank Munro discovers some desiccated bodies fallen out of vertical suspension tubes.]

This turns out to be the work of a vampire. The hero tries to destroy the monster by activating the self-destruct sequence of a shuttlecraft in the ship's hangar. But the vampire launches the shuttlecraft away from the ship, where it will explode harmlessly. In the end...

> ...the other vehicle explodes; the light from the explosion casts a sharp-contrast shadow through the view port in the shape of a cross that burns the vampire to ash. Just like you remembered! 
>  [image]

Comment: I found this by googling "vampire comic spaceship light cross." When I googled only "vampire comic spaceship," I found the story "Thirst" http://www.scaryforkids.com/thirst/ which was published a couple years earlier. The two stories are interesting complements to each other.

Comment: BRILLIANT work! This is exactly what I recalled! Thank you so much.